# How to get process ID in iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone

i need to to end a process in my iPhone for security issues so i need it's id 
How to get process ID in iPhone or iPad ?? in order to end it in Background process

Comment: Is this a process you created, or something that will already be running?  I don't think you'll be able to kill a process you didn't create even if you could get its ID.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "a process".  Do you mean you want to kill your app when it is quit rather than it going into the background, or do you mean you want to end some other process?  Your question is too vague.

Comment: Also, is this for a jailbroken device or a standard one?  If the latter, you probably won't be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 11):

Not entirely sure of what you actually need, but have a look at the `NSProcessInfo` API, expecially the value returned by `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]`.

As the documentation states, `NSProcessInfo` provides information about the *current process* only.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following:

```
- (NSArray *) runningProcesses {
    //CTL_KERN，KERN_PROC,KERN_PROC_ALL
    int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_ALL ,0};

    size_t miblen = 4;
    size_t size;
    int st = sysctl(mib, miblen, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    struct kinfo_proc * process = NULL;
    struct kinfo_proc * newprocess = NULL;

    do {
        size += size / 10;
        newprocess = realloc(process, size);

        if (!newprocess) {
            if (process) {
                free(process);
                process = NULL;
            }

            return nil;
        }

        process = newprocess;
        st = sysctl(mib, miblen, process, &size, NULL, 0);
    } while (st == -1 && errno == ENOMEM);

    if (st == 0) {      
        if (size % sizeof(struct kinfo_proc) == 0) {
            int nprocess = size / sizeof(struct kinfo_proc);
            if (nprocess) {             
                NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int i = nprocess - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
                    NSString * processID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_pid];
                    NSString * processName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", process[i].kp_proc.p_comm];

                    NSString * proc_CPU = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", process[i].kp_proc.p_estcpu];
                    double t = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - process[i].kp_proc.p_un.__p_starttime.tv_sec;
                    NSString * proc_useTiem = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",t];

                    //NSLog(@"process.kp_proc.p_stat = %c",process.kp_proc.p_stat);

                    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                    [dic setValue:processID forKey:@"ProcessID"];
                    [dic setValue:processName forKey:@"ProcessName"];
                    [dic setValue:proc_CPU forKey:@"ProcessCPU"];
                    [dic setValue:proc_useTiem forKey:@"ProcessUseTime"];

                    [processID release];
                    [processName release];
                    [proc_CPU release];
                    [proc_useTiem release];
                    [array addObject:dic];
                    [dic release];

                    [pool release];
                }

                free(process);
                process = NULL;

                NSLog(@"runningProcesses is === %@",array);
                return array;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;   
}
```